# Identify large differences within a sorted list

Tags: c#, list

Lets say i have a list of doubles:

```
0.0015
0.0016
0.0017
0.0019
0.0021
0.0022
0.0029
0.0030
0.0033
0.0036
```

And there's obviously a large difference in 0.0022 and 0.0029 compared to the rest, but is there a way i can make my C# program to be able to notice this difference within a sorted list W/O using a static threshold value. Because these data that i receive, the difference might not always be 0.0007 difference. So i would prefer if my program is able to be 'smart' enough to identify these 'large' differences and separate this list into multiple lists.

Comment: Guess you could calculate the _average_ or _median_ (up to you) difference and report all differences above those. (or you could report all differences the represent say, the top 25 precentile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i have understood your question correctly here goes. you may need to fill in a few gaps but you will get the drift with the below example:

```
List<double> doubleList = new List<double>{
    0.0015,
    0.0016,
    0.0017,
    0.0019,
    0.0021,
    0.0022,
    0.0029,
    0.0030,
    0.0033,
    0.0036
};

double averageDistance = 0.0;
double totals = 0.0;
double distance = 0.0;

for (int x = 0; x < (doubleList.Count - 1); x++)
{
    distance = doubleList[x] - doubleList[x + 1];
    totals += Math.Abs(distance);
}

averageDistance = totals / doubleList.Count;

// check to see if any distance between numbers is more than the average in the list
for (int x = 0; x < (doubleList.Count - 1); x++)
{
    distance = doubleList[x] - doubleList[x + 1];
    if (distance > averageDistance)
    {
        // this is where you have a gap that you want to do some split (etc)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i think i understand now. No idea why i didn't think of this. Brain can't function really well when i keep getting stuck. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the mean average (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) and the standard deviation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).  Use these to determine the values that fall outside of 'n' standard deviations.

Another approach would be to calculate all the differences between consecutive values, sort these (descending) and assume the top 'm' % of these difference values represent the largest changes.